# Remove element from multidimensional indexed array by value using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array:

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
            [1] => 18
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28
        )

)
```

And I'm trying to delete element by value using my function:

```
function removeElementWithValue($obj, $delete_value){

    if (!empty($obj->field)) {
         foreach($obj->field as $key =>$value){
            if (!empty($value)) {
                foreach($value as $k=>$v){
                    if($v == $delete_value){
                       $obj->field[$key][$k] = '';
                    }
                }
            }
         }
    }
    return urldecode(http_build_query($obj->field));
}

echo removeElementWithValue($request, '19');
```

After operation above I have: **5[0]=&5[1]=18&6[0]=28;** // Right!!!

```
echo removeElementWithValue($request, '18');
```

After operation above I have: **5[0]=&5[1]=&6[0]=28;** // Wrong ???

But my expected result after second operation is:

```
5[0]=19&5[1]=&6[0]=28;
```

Where is my mistake?
Thanks!

Comment: your function is for `StdClass Objects` and you are passing `array`. why ?

Comment: That's apparently not possible, as once you have deleted the value you, you cannot regain it. The alternative is make a copy of your original array to some other variable. now, apply your operations on the new copied variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_walk_recursive to find and change value

```
$arr = Array (
    5 => Array ( 0 => 19, 1 => 18 ),
    6 => Array ( 0 => 28));

$value = 18;

array_walk_recursive($arr, 
      function (&$item, $key, $v) { if ($item == $v) $item = ''; }, $value);

print_r($arr);
```

result:

```
Array (
    5 => Array ( 0 => 19, 1 =>  ),
    6 => Array ( 0 => 28));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler function might be..

```
function removeElementWithValue($ar,$val){

    foreach($ar as $k=>$array){
        //update the original value with a new array
        $new_ar = array_diff_key($array,array_flip(array_keys($array,$val)));
        if($new_ar){
            $ar[$k]=$new_ar;
        }else{
            unset($ar[$k]);//or remove the empty value
        }
    }

    return $ar;
}
```